# Increase Intensity of Vertex Group

Tags: particles, weight-painting, vertex-groups

I am trying to create some low poly mountains.

[image]

My issue concerns the pine trees, which I have added to make my lake look bigger. I have used the *Properties panel > Particles tab > Vertex Groups dropdown > Length:* setting to control the length of the trees (*Hair* particles), for added depth.

My *Weight Painting* for the *Length:* setting:

[image]

I like the transition, but **I'm wondering if it's possible to increase the intensity (i.e. lesser values become less, greater values become greater) to increase the contrast of the sizes between the trees in the foreground and background.**

Comment: Is that using several PS can be a solution?

Comment: @lemon Fair point. That would work. If no one can come up with a way to increase the intensity, I'll do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you go into weight paint mode with vertex select mask selected...

[image]

...and selected all your vertices, you can use the smooth button which works both ways.

[image]

Comment: Interesting idea, but this does not answer my question. This averages/increases the weight. I'm hoping for something that makes the high's higher and the low's lower. And perhaps not just to 1.0 and 0.0 weights, but to like 5 and -4, for example. Stark contrast!

Comment: "No weight will ever be set to values above 1.0 or below 0.0 regardless of the settings." Blender Manual. I understood that you wanted more contrast which is possible.